# Error using Watson Speech to Text in iOS application

Tags: ios, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I am trying to incorporate Watson Speech-to-Text into an iOS application.  In the past I am able to use the SDK just fine however with the new release of Watson Developer Cloud I have not had any success.

I already created the service in Bluemix for Watson STT.  In the iOS app, I pass in the credential and able to get the instance of STT, so connection is fine.  Looking at the SDK, it appears that I only need to call startListening() to have the app started listening on the users' speech.  However it throws an error immediately.

```
// Activate speech
stt.startListening()
```

Error message:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_retain_(swift::HeapObject*):
0x10108d1a0 <+0>:  cbz    x0, 0x10108d1b8           ; <+24>
0x10108d1a4 <+4>:  add    x8, x0, #8
0x10108d1a8 <+8>:  ldxr   w9, [x8]
0x10108d1ac <+12>: add    w9, w9, #4
->  0x10108d1b0 <+16>: stxr   w10, w9, [x8]
0x10108d1b4 <+20>: cbnz   w10, 0x10108d1a8          ; <+8>
0x10108d1b8 <+24>: ret
```

The error happens on the line with "->" and the message: com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient(6): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x1000e8008)

Appreciate any insight on this issue.

Comment: can you point me to the repository you are using ?

Comment: I use the following https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk.git

Comment: Andi there is a new release in the ios-sdk that includes continuous listening and an example of how to use it. Take a look at https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk/releases/tag/v0.2